# How model class "Name" becomes plural "Names" under Admin Page?

Tags: django-models, django-admin

In Django's tutorial, a models.py class is created named "**Question**" (singular).  It is also registered to be included within the Admin Page using  `admin.site.register(Question)` (singular)

But then under the Admin Page, it's listed as "**Questions**" (plural)

Is Django automatically renaming things under the Admin Page to be grammatically satisfying?

[Django's Tutorial.. add "Question" to Admin Page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin)

[link to png of Admin Page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_images/admin03t.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the model definition of the Question you can control this by declaring the Meta class:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'
```

You can find this here [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural)

As explained in the docs, 'If this isn’t given, Django will use verbose_name + "s".'